# Бесконечная загрузка сайта и админки на Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

В один момент при попытке изменить статью на сайте (Wordpress) и сайт и сама админка перестали адекватно грузиться, просто висит оооочень долго загрузка и ничего не происходит. Зашел в phpmyadmin, там, в разделе состояние такое вот:

**Сетевой трафик с момента запуска: 8.2 ТБ
Сервер MySQL работает 36 дней, 9 часов, 20 минут и 45 секунд. Запущен Мар 15 2018 г., 09:32.**

Как-то многовато, мне кажется) 
По статистике запросов:

**Вопросов начиная с запуска: 2,346,084,760 Документация
ø в час: 2,686,135
ø в минуту: 44,769
ø в секунду: 746**

Больше всего сожрало:
**select    1,852 M 2,120.5 k   78.94%**

Что делать, ребят?

Answer (score 0):

Искать причину.

Отключить все плагины через ftp. Для этого переименовать папки плагинов в точка-имя, например `.woocommerce`. При обновлении страницы WordPress потеряет их из виду и отключит.

Сменить тему на стандартную.

Потом постепенно включать все назад и смотреть, какая комбинация плагинов (или тема) подвешивает сайт.

Comment: Отключены все плагины, тему менял, проблема осталась(

Comment: @Mils на голом ВП такое? Значит настраивай сервер. Логи в помощь. И инструменты профилирования.

Comment: @SeVlad да сказки. На голом wp бесконечная загрузка и 746 запросов в секунду. Там явно свой кривой код.